# Triangulation Three.js algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, three.js, triangulation, dat.gui

I am trying to make a triangulation algorithm, following simple rules, in javascript using Three.js.

Here are the actual steps:

[image]

We start with a square and "randomly" define heights for the cells, after a symmetric division in four parts.

I intend to make the "steps" with a dat.GUI panel.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me!

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you want this triangulation to occur (Javascript? Vertex shader?)

Comment: Why would you write your own triangulation algorithm? Fast and reliable triangulation algorithms are very complicated, if you don't have any mathematical background I would suggest you stick with one of the existing triangulation libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Just use existing lib to get TIN data. For example earcut (some THREEJS examples already uses it). You can use earcut (trianle face data) output to create mesh with custom buffer geometry.
I prefer to use PostGIS for this (server-side processing). ST_DelaunayTriangles and ST_Tesselate are perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Yea I was onto that to very impressed with your idea triangulation are for treasure hunt maybe that's where to look I want to do 4 normal form squared triangulation for movement into analytics encryption dna something like 4 forth part of the trumpet gravity = triangulated down when its not on top of something pretty much an mri in a rocket for space travel type piston transmission [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbmzZ.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deKB4.jpg)